# Spring MVC Controller method that won't affect session timeout

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Spring MVC REST method that is called periodically by my application to poll for notifications in the background. I would like for this method to not affect the session timeout, so that users are still logged out automatically if they leave the browser window open without any interaction.

Is it possible to annotate a Spring MVC controller method so that it won't affect the session timeout?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the session timeout is managed at the container level, far above Spring controllers. And I do not know any Java EE trick to say that some request should not reset session timeout.

The only thing I can imagine would be to report the timeout in the front-end application : if there is no user interaction for a determined timeout, the front-end automatically sends a disconnection request.